# Mock async action in Pinia

Tags: vue.js, pinia, vitest

I have a simple component that triggers an async Pinia-action (on button click) followed by a `router.push()`.

Now I try to unit test that behavior, specific I'm expecting the `router.push`. But somehow it does not call, unless I remove the call (or the await) to the async action.

##### Component

```js
async function resolve() {
    await store.resolveId() // it works if I remove this line (or remove the await)
    if (store.apiUrl) {
        router.push('/')
    }
}
```

##### Test

```js
        it('should redirect to root', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(SelectTenant, {
                global: {
                    plugins: [createTestingPinia()]
                }
            })

            wrapper.find('#resolveButton').trigger('click')

            expect(useRouter().push).toHaveBeenCalled() // this fails
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I found a solution (or a workaround, don't know):

```js
import { mount, flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'
// ...
await flushPromises()
expect(useRouter().push).toHaveBeenCalled() // OK
```